# Grand Total Value changing When Apply Any Filter In Power BI DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to do percentage of grand total. When i created the measure like

= Calculate(DistinctCount(ColumnName1),AllSelected(ColumnName2))

It gives me Overall Grand Total for that. But when i select perticular week then the Grand Total changes
For example rand Total is 23872
when i select week number from filter for week number 23 then it showing Grand Total 1232
I want to subtract the week number total from grand total i.e 1232/23872.

The 23872 this grand total should not change when apply any filter.

Comment: Why do you think the grand total shouldn't change?

Comment: If i apply any filter the grand total is changing. i don't want to change the grand total.

Comment: Might be good to have a dataset and some concret example of what you have done so far and what you expect ?